Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted into Bugsnag library
I see a few errors like this (different parts of Bugsnap):
production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) at /var/www/html/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag/src/Report.php:683)

But I have memory_limit=3G for PHP CLI and FPM, and I don't have 'ini_set' for memory_limit into PHP code.
So my question is: how I can find and fix the source of these errors?

Have you checked if your PHP settings are used? What does phpinfo() or php -info (CLI) say?

@Marcel, yes:

memory_limit => 4096M => 4096M [CLI]
memory_limit 2048M [Phpinfo script]

So I have no idea why PHP may use the default 132M limit...
